# Combine Two Queries with Separate Indexes

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that pull data from two different tables, but I need them to pull in the same report. I have a shared key between them, and the first table has one entry that corresponds to many entries in the second table.

My first query:

```
SELECT Proposal_ID,
    substr(Proposal_Name, 1, 3) AS Prefix,
    substr(Proposal_Name, 4, 6) AS `Number`,
    Institution,
    CollegeCode,
    DepartmentCode,
    Proposer_FirstName,
    Proposer_LastName

FROM proposals.proposal
WHERE Institution = 'T';
```

Sample Data:

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| ID | Prefix | Number | Inst. | CollCode | DeptCode | FirstName | LastName |
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 18 | SYP    | 4675   | T     | AS       | SOC      | Linda     | McGaff   |
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 20 | GEO    | 4340   | T     | AS       | SGS      | Teddy     | Graham   |
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

My second query:

```
SELECT Parent_Proposal,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`status`.`Status_Code` ORDER BY `status`.`Status_Time` DESC), ',', 1) AS status_code,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`status`.`Status_Time` ORDER BY `status`.`Status_Time` DESC), ',', 1) AS status_timestamp
FROM proposals.`status`    
GROUP BY `status`.Parent_Proposal
```

Sample Data:

```
+-----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| Parent_Proposal | Status_Code | Status_Time          |
+-----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 18              | 40          | 2016-11-09 06:30:35  |
+-----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 20              | 11          | 2017-03-20 10:26:31  |
+-----------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

I basically need to pull the most recent Status_Code and Status_Timestamp based on the Status_Timestamp and then relate that to the first table with the Parent_Proposal column.

Is there a way to group a subset of results without grouping all of the data together?

Expected Result:

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-------+--------+-------------+----------------------+
| ID | Prefix | Number | Inst. | CollCode | DeptCode | FName | LName  | Status_Code | Status_Time          |
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-------+--------+-------------+----------------------+
| 18 | SYP    | 4675   | T     | AS       | SOC      | Linda | McGaff | 40          | 2016-11-09 06:30:35  |
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-------+--------+-------------+----------------------+
| 20 | 11     | GEO    | 4340  | AS       | SGS      | Teddy | Graham | 11          | 2017-03-20 10:26:31  |
+----+--------+--------+-------+----------+----------+-------+--------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Thanks for any help and insight!

Comment: Some sample data would be nice, along with an explanation of how these two tables are related via the data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've updated the question with sample data. The first table's 'ID' corresponds to the second table's 'Parent_Proposal'

Comment: OK you're almost there.  Now just show us what output you expect based on this data, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this.  Just join your two tables together, and then do an additional join to a subquery on the `status` table to find the latest record for each parent proposal.

```
SELECT
    p.Proposal_ID,
    SUBSTR(p.Proposal_Name, 1, 3) AS Prefix,
    SUBSTR(p.Proposal_Name, 4, 6) AS Number,
    p.Institution,
    p.CollegeCode,
    p.DepartmentCode,
    p.Proposer_FirstName,
    p.Proposer_LastName,
    s1.Status_Code,
    s1.Status_Time 
FROM proposals.proposal p
LEFT JOIN proposals.status s1
    ON p.ID = s1.Parent_Proposal
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Parent_Proposal, MAX(Status_Time) AS Max_Status_Time
    FROM proposals.status
    GROUP BY Parent_Proposal
) s2
    ON s1.Parent_Proposal = s2.Parent_Proposal AND s1.Status_Time = s2.Max_Status_Time
WHERE
    p.Institution = 'T';
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't realize you could sub-select within a join.